# How to retrieve mysql data with php?

Tags: php, mysql, database

i have the following database:

```
  id  |  user  |    grades
  1   |    1   |  08-09-10; 07-06-08; 05-04-07 
  2   |    3   |  10-09-06; 05-04-03...
```

Is there a way to get this:

```
 id | user  | grade1 | grade2 | grade3 |
 1  |   1   |   08   |    09  |   10   |
 2  |   1   |   07   |    06  |   08   |
 3  |   1   |   05   |    04  |   07   |
 4  |   3   |   10   |    09  |   06   |
```

to retrieve the data?

THx for all help.

Comment: I would first ask what grade is, and would there ever be more then 3, also how do they relate? this way we can suggest a better structure if needed.

Comment: Yes, can be more than 3, i sent just a sample, there´s the class row too.

Comment: What you are desiring is not "normalized"

Comment: Question edited Mike.Thx.

Comment: I would **strongly** recommend changing the schema of your database and writing a SQL script to re-organize the data into a normalized structure like the one suggested below. To do that however, you would need to use the query that you're requesting to break up the data. But once you did, all following queries will be *much* easier. This, of course, all depends on how big your application is and how many other queries you would need to change, so unless you are at the beginning of development, then it might not be the best option to do that. I'm not somewhere I can help with the query atm.

Comment: That´s what i´m trying to do. i didn´t create the database, i got it done, i´m trying to fix it.

Comment: Perhaps read into database normalization https://www.google.co.uk/search?site=&source=hp&ei=Py0rVM3FL8bDPPSUgZAJ&q=database+normalization&oq=database+norm&gs_l=mobile-gws-hp.1.0.0l5.1177.3592.0.4265.14.12.0.3.3.0.356.2083.0j8j1j2.11.0....0...1c.1.54.mobile-gws-hp..5.9.1405.0._NciDx2aoCI

Answer (score 0):

With out all of your data and table structures its hard to give you code to resolve your problem.  Also here at SO you need to provided code that you have tried that we can help you fix.  That being said I would break this into 3 tables, `user_tbl`, `class_tbl`, `grade_tbl` this will allow for the most flexibility moving forward instead of just putting yourself in another limiting table structure.

The data structure would look something like this, and you would use `INNER JOIN` to pull the data back together.

```
user_tbl
    id
    name

class_tbl
    id
    name

grade_tbl
    id
    user_id
    class_id
    grade
```

If you revise your question with code you have tried and your complete data structure I will revise my answer to help you complete your task.

Comment: The data is already in the database, the table have this rows: id; userid, name, class,signupdate,grades, i´m made another table, with this rows: id;userid,grade1,grade2,grade3,grade4,grade5, this way i can get the user who gets 2 or more grades bigger than 8 (for example).